# Определение классов qt

Tags: c++, qt

Изучаю `qt` и столкнулся с таким (обсолютно не понятным для меня) примером:

```
//headerfile.hpp
#include <QWidget>
#include <QStack>
//вопрос по эти двум стокам
class QLCDNumber;
class QPushButton;
...
```

Поясню: в хэдэре создается класс, унаследованный от `QWidget` (это понятно) и в нем используются классы `QLCDNumber` и `QPushButton`, но (судя по тому что выдает компилятор при проверке кода) эти классы не определены в `QWidget` и без указания этих классов (те две строки) код не скомпилировать. Ну или подключить `QtWidgets`. Почему так? Как это вообще работает?

Comment: forward declaration, что-ли? Хорошо бы приводить ПОЛНЫЙ минимально необходимый пример, по обрывкам что-то понять сложно...

Comment: @AlexeyEsaulenko какой полный? Реализацию класса, который идет ниже? Чем это поможет?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это называется forward declaration, по этому словосочетанию найдете полно информации. Вкратце: мы сообщаем компилятору что у нас где-то дальше будет использоваться класс с именем QLCDNumber, зачем это нужно? Могу сразу два варианта предложить:

- Для сокрытия деталей реализации. Таким методом реализован шаблон-программирования PIMPL, т.е. в заголовочном файле виден только указатель на класс.
- Для минимизации подключенных заголовков, что должно положительно повлиять на скорость компиляции программы.

Comment: Я так и думал, что связано, с минимизацией подключенных заголовков, но ведь дальше все равно нужно подключать нужный - так в чем выгода?

Comment: Если подключать хидеры в cpp файлы, то они буду компилироваться только в текущей единице трансляции. Если хидеры подключать в h файле, то они будут компилироваться в текущей единице трансляции и во всех остальных, которые включают текущий хидер. По-этому нужно стараться избегать лишних включений в h файле, иначе может раздуться время компиляции проекта.

Answer (score 2):

forward declaration используется, если есть зависимости между классами. Например:

```
class b;

class a{

b bb;

public:

};

class b{

a aa;

public:

};
```

В этом примере в момент трансляции класса **"b"** класс **"a"** уже определен. Но в момент трансляции класса **"a"** класс **"b"** еще не определен. Чтобы сказать транслятору, что **"b"** это тоже класс и применяется forward declaration в виде строки **class b;**.

UPD1:

Более реалистичный пример для forward declaration:

```
class b;

class a{

b bb;

public:

};

class b{

public:

void fun1(a* aa);

};
```